# @JsonTypeInfo and UnrecognizedPropertyException "type" deserializing Geojson

Tags: jackson, geojson

I need to deserialize geojson.
Json-example "Polygon" i got from: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id4

```
String polygonJson = "{ \"type\": \"Polygon\",\n" +
        "    \"coordinates\": [\n" +
        "      [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]\n" +
        "      ]\n" +
        "   }";


Polygon pol = new ObjectMapper().readValue(polygonJson, Polygon.class); // fails :-(
```

Method readValue fails with:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "type" (class org.geojson.Polygon), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "interiorRings", "crs", "bbox", "coordinates", "exteriorRing"])
 at [Source: { "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
      ]
   }; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: org.geojson.Polygon["type"])
```

Implementation of parent class in org.geogson library:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(property = "type", use = Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(Feature.class), @Type(Polygon.class), @Type(MultiPolygon.class), @Type(FeatureCollection.class),
        @Type(Point.class), @Type(MultiPoint.class), @Type(MultiLineString.class), @Type(LineString.class),
                @Type(GeometryCollection.class) })
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public abstract class GeoJsonObject implements Serializable {...}
```

It uses property called 'type' to find out what actual class is represented by json string.
Why this property is unrecognized ?

Comment: `Polygon pol = new ObjectMapper().readValue(polygonJson, GeoJsonObject .class);` can you try `GeoJsonObject`?

Comment: You cant write that way. You can do this:
GeoJsonObject obj = om.readValue(polygonJson, GeoJsonObject.class); - but then you get another exeption because GeoJsonObject is abstract :
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.geojson.GeoJsonObject, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information

Comment: What version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: <jackson.version>2.6.4</jackson.version>

Comment: @abkvandrd hm that is really strange, because i tried both ways `Polygon polygon = mapper.readValue(json, Polygon.class);` and with `GeoJsonObject.class` and both of them work just fine on my setup. Same jackson and i tesed all  `geojson-jackson` from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.grundid.opendatalab/geojson-jackson. Maybe jackson just can't see geojson classes for some strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so your problem is that you are not giving enough info to @Type annotation. You need to add **name** so change it to look like this and it should work:

```
@JsonSubTypes({ 
    @Type(value = Feature.class, name = "Feature"), 
    @Type(value = Polygon.class, name = "Polygon")
    ... and so on!
```

Comment: How can I change source code ? It is not mine.
It is from this library:
https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson/blob/master/src/main/java/org/geojson/GeoJsonObject.java

Comment: Couldn't find that lib anywhere, where did you got it?

Comment: Found it, i'm maybe blind :)